# Is there eclipse restart event?

Tags: eclipse

Is there an event fired on eclipse restart? If there is such a event, how can I register a listener to it?

Answer (score 1):

See [IWorkbenchListener#preShutdown](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchListener.html).